# Change number of widget columns in dashboard?

Tags: widgets, dashboard

I removed some widgets from the dashboard in the wrong way (using `unset()` on `$wp_meta_boxes`) and as a side effect my dashboard widget area is now split into 4 columns, but with just the first 2 having the normal default widgets in, thus the page is squashed.

Is there a way to change the amount of widget columns in the dashboard? They are all active as I can drag and drop the widgets around, but now 4 is too many. I am using Wordpress 3.1.3 so don't have the new admin interface yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under "Screen Options", you can change the number of columns. Does that fix your problem?

[image: Dashboard with Number of Columns option visible]

Comment: That's what I read about, but I don't have screen options box :S

Comment: Gah it was a plugin disabling it! Sorted it now, thanks.